# How do you get multiple desktops that is connected through a router then to a laptop, to access the laptop's internet connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, ip-address

I have multiple Desktops connected to a router (via cable) connected to a laptop that has a wireless internet connection,
Desktops -> Router -> laptop -> wirelessly connected to main router/modern

I already came across an article (http://ccm.net/forum/affich-39151-connect-laptop-and-pc-to-share-internet-conn) that explained how to get a desktop directly connected to a laptop to share its internet connection (The method works but I need to get them all connected at the same time), but my situation seems a bit different since i have multiple desktops connected though a router to the laptop

*""It appears that I need to setup the router or desktop IP address correctly to get it to work, or route the address through the router, anyone know how?""*

Using a linksys router WRT100, Operating systems are windows 7
[Network Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfIAI.png)

EDIT

The primary router is on the other side of the house so cascading them with a ethernet cable remains an impractical solution, The WRT router does not support "bridging", this question is one that would require knowledge of networking of how to properly set up the router and configure the ip address of the desktops. this should be a quick fix solution

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but why in the world are you trying to do this? They make devices EXACTLY for this purpose. Look up "Wireless Bridge" http://us.dlink.com/resource-centre/how-to-guides/how-to-extend-your-network-with-a-wireless-bridge/

Comment: I didn't tell you to cascade the router with your primary router. You can "cascade" it with your laptop instead. Just look at the article I linked to and replace "modem/main router" with "laptop".

Comment: When you tell windows to share your internet connection, your windows machine will start to act as a router.

Comment: 1. a wireless bridge only extends the range of the network so you can axcess it further aways

Comment: however there is also a different type of bridge that connects to routers wirelessly but my router can not support that feature

Comment: I need to be able to connect  "multiple" desktops though my laptop and that only works with 1 connected the the laptop's ethernet jack

Comment: I undertood what you want and I already gave you a solution that will work for this. Just read through everything again.

Comment: If your secondary router does not support bridging then use the "LAN to LAN" method described in the article I linked. That will always work.

Comment: [I'll just leave this here...](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003RCEAB8)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this article.
https://www.linksys.com/ca/support-article?articleNum=132275

Your laptop plays the role of the "main router" and modem combined while your router plays the role of the "secondary router".

Comment: The primary router is on the other side of the house so cascading them with a ethernet cable remains an impractical solution

Comment: You are not supposed to cascade your sec. router with your primary but with your laptop. Read my other comments.

Comment: for that to work i would need a networking switch for the amount of computers i have

Comment: But you already have a router connected to your laptop. It should have enough ports.

Comment: yes but the desktops need to be configured properly to over a "router", witch is why i need the correct set of instructions to point the ip address properly

Comment: the article is useful in getting the router connect with the laptops network adapter possibly, but i need to still point the ip addresses of the desktops to though the router, and then to the labtops network adapter (and possibly the actual main router), and set the subnet of the devices, so instructions like those linked in the question, that would also point me  through the router would be most helpful

Comment: The desktops should be configured exactly as if they were connected to the main router. Windows' default network settings should work fine. So no need to manually set an ip. But the router needs to have an ip that's different from your laptop's ip.

Comment: The router I'm trying to connect through is not the main router so the settings required are different those in the article